# Docker dotnet publish output not found

Tags: .net, docker, output, dotnet-publish

I am trying to successfully build/publish a project using a dockerfile. However, for some reason it cannot find the output folder that it should of created. From the other posts, everything looks correct in my docker file.

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish ./ClassLibrary2.csproj -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ClassLibrary2.dll"]
```

Directory

[image]

Docker Command(ran from the folder where the docker file lies): docker build -f Dockerfile-SignedAssembly -t signed-assembly .
Output:

[image]

Updated Image with missing bat file
[image]

Comment: You can't run a class library, because it doesn't contain a suitable Main method. Try using the `console` template to start from instead.

Comment: @HansKilian Sorry what’s the console template? I can also test using an console app.

Comment: It's what you get if you do `dotnet new console` instead of `dotnet new classlib`. It looks like you use Visual Studio. I don't know how to get it from in there.

Comment: @HansKilian thanks for the advice! Will try that

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks! it works with the ConsoleApp. One last question, I am trying to run a post build event which is within my .net project already. It needs to run a batch file however docker is saying that the file cannot be found in the /app directory. When I list the files in the directory before the publish it says it is there. (See screenshot of error)

Comment: You are trying to run a `.bat` file in a Linux environment. That's not going to work, Linux doesn't support that. just like it can't run Windows executables (`.exe`) files. You could try using a shell script (`.sh`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

just replace `COPY --from=build /app/out .` by `COPY --from=build /out .`  as shown below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish ./ClassLibrary2.csproj -c Release -o /out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ClassLibrary2.dll"]
```